# get the permalink never return with empty value

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

hello am trying to check if there's a url to the custom post type inside default post type page
so i used

```
if(get_the_permalink($customID)){
echo 'true';
}else{
echo 'false';
}
```

it's always echo true even if the $customID not exists
is there's way to do that with `get_the_permalink();` function 
and i know about `get_post_status()` but i need to do it with `get_the_permalink`

Comment: `'$customID'` is a string, have you tried `$customID`?

Comment: thanks milo i just update my question i typed it wrongly

Comment: How are you getting $customID?

Comment: Either your problem is elsewhere or you need to add more detail to this question. `get_the_permalink` *definitely* returns false if the post ID passed to it doesn't exist.

Comment: am using it inside loop so if $customID value is empty the function get the default post url so it's alway return true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check if `$customID` is set, first. E.g.

```
if ($customID && get_permalink ($customID)) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```